# dateutil.parse で指定したタイムゾーン時刻として読みたい

Tags: python

```
import datetime
import pytz
import dateutil.parser

dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2021-03-02 06:00:00')
print(dt)
print(dt.tzinfo)
print(dt.date())

dt_utc = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
print(dt_utc)
print(dt_utc.tzinfo)
print(dt_utc.date())
```

を実行すると

```
2021-03-02 06:00:00
None
2021-03-02
2021-03-01 21:00:00+00:00
UTC
2021-03-01
```

となってしまい parse はローカル時間 JST で生成されるようです
これをUTCに変換してしまうと日付がずれてしまいます

時刻文字列のフォーマットに自由度もたせたいので strptime ではなく parse でよみたいのですが

```
'2020-03-02 06:00:00'     => UTC 3/2 06:00
'2020-03-02 06:00:00+900' => UTC 3/1 21:00
```

という感じでタイムゾーン指定がある場合はそのタイムゾーン文字列として読み込み
何もない場合にUTCとして読み込んで最終的に生成する datetime オブジェクトは UTC として生成したいです

dateutil.parse では実現できないでしょうか？

Comment: 変換後の`tzinfo`が`None`だったら、文字列に`Z`か`+00:00`を連結して再変換するとか？

Comment: parse() のデフォルトの timezone を UTC にすれば良いかと。`dateutil.parser.parse('...', default=dateutil.parser.parse('00:00Z')).astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz('UTC'))`

Comment: うまくいきました！

Comment: 解決しているようですし、自己回答なさってはいかがでしょうか(自己回答は推奨されています)。現在この質問は未解決の質問に分類されています。せっかくプラス評価されている質問でもありますし、このままではもったいないなと思いました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントでいただいた通り

```
import datetime
import pytz
import dateutil.parser

dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2021-03-02 06:00:00', default=dateutil.parser.parse('00:00Z'))
print(dt)
print(dt.tzinfo)
print(dt.date())

dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2021-03-02T06:00:00+0900', default=dateutil.parser.parse('00:00Z'))
print(dt)
print(dt.tzinfo)
print(dt.date())
```

という感じで default キーを設定するとタイムゾーン不明な場合にUTCにしてくれるようです

```
2021-03-02 06:00:00+00:00
tzutc()
2021-03-02
2021-03-02 06:00:00+09:00
tzoffset(None, 32400)
2021-03-02
```

```
.astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz('UTC'))
```

をつければ UTC になりますが
DB にいれるところで変換してるので正しく tz 情報がついてるということで解決しました